# Warning : requires 10 reputation to answer on this question while having 4k+ reputation?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure why, but this is for the first time, I'm already logged-in into StackOverflow site, I was answering on this question, [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/27120016#27120016) and a warning popup came out with text, "You need at least 10 reputation on this site to answer this question." [Something similar]. Ah, I've already 4k+ reputation on it, still that warning, why? I scroll up to check whether I logged-in or not, (Yes, I was logged-in) I copied my answer, and reload (refresh) the page, and I was able to post my answer again. Note, that question is protected before.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone gets this warning; it indicates that the question has been *protected*.

Protection prevents spammers and "me too" posters from adding their wonderful contributions to the question.  It is employed when a question has been linked to from Reddit, or for whatever reason is receiving disproportionate attention.

Comment: NOT everyone will gets this warning, will you get this warning too?

Comment: Yes, I will get this warning too.  Were you actually able to post, despite this warning?

Comment: But this is the first time, that I got this warning even if I've 4k+ rep, isn't a bug?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on something... Were you actually able to post or not?

Comment: Yes, after I got that warning, I reload the page, and I was able to post despite this warning.

Comment: Well, I think you were just seeing the protection banner then.  Everyone sees the protection banner, and it may take a different form on mobile.

Comment: I don't know about protection banner, but yes, that was a warning (again, a warning in red background and white text coloured) with similar texts I've written in question.